# Fedora 24 Vagrant issue. mount.nfs access denied by server

Tags: ruby, vagrant

I started using fedora 24 last year for my study/work computer. First time I run into an issue I cannot figure out within a reasonable amount of time.

We need to use Vagrant for a project, and I'm trying to get it running on my computer. The command **vagrant up** fails at the mounting nfs. Here's the output after the command:

```
Bringing machine 'default' up with 'libvirt' provider...
==> default: Starting domain.
==> default: Waiting for domain to get an IP address...
==> default: Waiting for SSH to become available...
==> default: Creating shared folders metadata...
==> default: Exporting NFS shared folders...
==> default: Preparing to edit /etc/exports. Administrator privileges will be required...
[sudo] password for feilz: 
Redirecting to /bin/systemctl status  nfs-server.service
● nfs-server.service - NFS server and services
Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/nfs-server.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
Drop-In: /run/systemd/generator/nfs-server.service.d
       └─order-with-mounts.conf
Active: active (exited) since Wed 2017-02-15 15:17:58 EET; 19h ago
Main PID: 16889 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
Tasks: 0 (limit: 512)
CGroup: /system.slice/nfs-server.service

Feb 15 15:17:58 feilz systemd[1]: Starting NFS server and services...
Feb 15 15:17:58 feilz systemd[1]: Started NFS server and services.
==> default: Mounting NFS shared folders...
The following SSH command responded with a non-zero exit status.
Vagrant assumes that this means the command failed!

mount -o 'vers=4' 192.168.121.1:'/home/feilz/env/debian64' /vagrant

Stdout from the command:



Stderr from the command:

stdin: is not a tty
mount.nfs: access denied by server while mounting 192.168.121.1:/home/feilz/env/debian64
```

My Vagrantfile looks like: (I skipped the commented out lines)

```
Vagrant.configure(2) do |config|
   config.vm.box = "debian/jessie64"
   config.vm.provider :libvirt do |libvirt|
        libvirt.driver = "qemu"
   end
end
```

I can run the **vagrant ssh** command to log in, and write the command

```
sudo mount -o 'vers=4' 192.168.121.1:'/home/feilz/env/debian64' /vagrant
```

inside vagrant to try again.Then the output becomes

```
mount.nfs: access denied by server while mounting 192.168.121.1:/home/feilz/env/debian64
```

I've gone through loads of webpages. I fixed missing ruby gems (nokogiri and libffi). I tried modifying the /etc/exports file, it doesn't work, and it gets reset after I run vagrant halt / up.

I have installed the vagrant plugin vagrant-libvirt

What haven't I tried yet, that would allow me to use the NFS file sharing for Vagrant?